# Maze game using enums to decide which text is printed

Tags: java

I am making a maze game. What I am trying to do is print different messages when a user bumps into a wall depending on a random number. The number is generated by the random number generator.  For this, I am using enums because I thought it would be easier, but I am having a problem.  The class GameManager  takes all the inputs from the user and decides what to do with them. When I call the print statement for textcard.cardtype.WALL, it returns null and I am not sure why. I am pretty sure my problem has to do with my getCard method. I am trying to return that text card in that class but I am not sure if I did it right anyway.  Below are my enums and wall method.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class TextCard
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String text;//text in the card
    private int number;
    private TextCard text1;
    public enum CardType{
        WALL, TRAP
    }
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class TextCard
     */
    //messages that will appear throughout the game
    public TextCard(CardType cardType)
    {
       if(cardType == (CardType.WALL)){
           wallCard();
        }

    }
    public String wallCard(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        number = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
        if(number < 20){
            return ("wall1");
    }
    if(20 < number && number > 40){
        return ("wall2");
    }
    if(40 < number && number > 60){
        return ("wall3");
    }
    if(60 < number && number > 80){
        return ("wall4");
    }
    else{
        return ("wall5");
    }
  }
  public TextCard getCard(){
      return text1;
    }

}
```

METHOD CALL IN GAMEMANAGER

```
System.out.println(new TextCard(TextCard.CardType.WALL).getCard());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(new TextCard(TextCard.CardType.WALL).wallCard());
```

I don't know why you want a method to return the object itself, you would have that already. I assume you want to call your method to get the random string.

Also, you could make the wallCard method static so you don't need a new instance of TextCard that would be just deleted right after the print

```
public static String wallCard(){
```

This would then be used like so

```
System.out.println(TextCard.wallCard());
```

To explain what is wrong with the code you posted, you call wallCard() in the constructor which returns the random string but you don't store it. The getCard() method isn't clear, but it looks like with how you call it in the print, you want it to return the random string. If you want just 1 random string to reuse, you need to use the text String variable. So in the constructor, do this

```
text = wallCard();
```

then in getCard(), return text. It would need to return a String.

Answer (score 1):

Best to do:

```
TextCard newcard = new TextCard();
newcard.getString();
```

And in TextCard:

```
public String getString() {
  return taco; // where taco is a string at the class level
}
```

Your .getCard() method returns a TextCard object *within* your TextCard class that you never assigned to anything.

Instead of returning text1, forget the text1 variable and just `return this;` in your getCard() method.

This will get you *the object itself* which will look like garbage: TextCard@5c647e05

To get any values of that object, you'll need to do getCard().getThing() and include a getThing method in your card class that returns the "thing" (be it an int, String, etc.)

Comment: awesome thank you that at least got it to print but now I have a new problem, instead of printing "wall1" or any of those other strings I get outputs like this TextCard@51bb2547

Comment: Whoever is calling getCard() on an instance would already have that instance. OP probably didn't mean to return the instance itself in a getter. Maybe they mean to return the strings

Comment: yeah I am trying to print a random string based on the number generator

Comment: that is because now you are returning an object. to get a variable of that object you will need to write other methods, like getNumber in you TextCard class. and then call .getCard().getNumber() to get the number assigned to that instance of the card object

Comment: so I can leave my getCard method as getCard(){return this} but then I have to write another method thats like getString or something which returns the string inside getCard and in game manager id need to call ,getCard().getString()

Comment: @REEE exactly - or if you store the card object from within your main method, TextCard newcard = new TextCard(), you could later do newcard.getString()

Comment: okay I think I understand so for my getString method though what am I returning? I have public String getString{ return what?}  how do I return the string that the random number generator is going to generate?

Comment: for that you can write a method: `public int getNum() { return number; }`

Comment: @REEE if you want the random generated string see my answer. You don't need to do all this

Comment: wait so i need a getCard, getString, and a getNum method? and the getNum method would call getString which would call getCard?

Comment: I think this has become over-complicated. I was trying to show you generic ways of accessing variables associated with instances of classes (objects) you create. I agree with @Tyler in that if you want the simplest case, do what he suggests.

Comment: I edited my answer to store the String in the variable created.

Comment: So idk if you guys are still here but I have another issue.  So the whole point of me making this text card class is so i can apply a border or pictures to every textcard.  so I wanted to define a border like" **************" in the constructor and so the constructor would create a text card with the string generated by the RNG plus the border defined in the constructor.  how do I do that if im only printing the string?